# Using Scrapy to parse table page and extract data from underlying links

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the underlying data on the table in the following pages: https://www.un.org/sc/suborg/en/sanctions/1267/aq_sanctions_list/summaries

What I want to do is access the underlying link for each row, and capture:

1. The ID tag (e.g. QDE001),
2. The name
3. The reason for listing / additional information
4. Other linked entities

This is what I have, but it does not seems to be working, I keep getting a "NotImplementedError('{}.parse callback is notdefined'.format(self.*class*.*name*)).I believe that the Xpaths I have defined are OK, not sure what I am missing.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class UNSCItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    uid = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    reason = scrapy.Field()
    add_info = scrapy.Field()



class UNSC(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "UNSC"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.un.org/sc/suborg/en/sanctions/1267/aq_sanctions_list/summaries?type=All&page=0',      
        'https://www.un.org/sc/suborg/en/sanctions/1267/aq_sanctions_list/summaries?type=All&page=1',
        'https://www.un.org/sc/suborg/en/sanctions/1267/aq_sanctions_list/summaries?type=All&page=2',
        'https://www.un.org/sc/suborg/en/sanctions/1267/aq_sanctions_list/summaries?type=All&page=3',
        'https://www.un.org/sc/suborg/en/sanctions/1267/aq_sanctions_list/summaries?type=All&page=4',
        'https://www.un.org/sc/suborg/en/sanctions/1267/aq_sanctions_list/summaries?type=All&page=5',
        'https://www.un.org/sc/suborg/en/sanctions/1267/aq_sanctions_list/summaries?type=All&page=6',]

    rules = Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/sc/suborg/en/sanctions/1267/aq_sanctions_list/summaries/',)),callback='data_extract')


    def data_extract(self, response):
        item = UNSCItem()
        name = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/article/div[3]/div//text()').extract()
        uid = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/article/div[2]/div/div//text()').extract()
        reason =  response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/article/div[6]/div[2]/div//text()').extract() 
        add_info = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/article/div[7]//text()').extract()
        related = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/article/div[8]/div[2]//text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below approach. It should fetch you all the `ids` and corresponding `names` from all the six pages. I suppose, the rest of the fields you can manage yourself.

Just run it as it is:

```
import scrapy

class UNSC(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "UNSC"

    start_urls = ['https://www.un.org/sc/suborg/en/sanctions/1267/aq_sanctions_list/summaries?type=All&page={}'.format(page) for page in range(0,7)]

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"views-table")]//tbody//tr'):
            idnum = item.xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"views-field-field-reference-number")]/text()').extract()[-1].strip()
            name = item.xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"views-field-title")]//span[@dir="ltr"]/text()').extract()[-1].strip()
            yield{'ID':idnum,'Name':name}
```